# Mudar String para Number em uma lista

Tags: javascript, array

Me pediram pra fazer as somas dos arrays:

```
const lista = [1, 4, 9, 18]

let soma = 0;

for(let x = 0; x < lista.length; x++) {
    soma += lista[x];
}
console.log(soma)
```

resultado:

```
32
```

até ai tudo bem e tambem pediu pra fazer uma com string:

```
const lista = [1, '4', 9, 18]

let soma = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < lista.length; x++) {
    soma += lista[x];
}
console.log(soma)
```

Resultado:

```
14918
```

Tentei usar parseInt

```
const lista = [1, '4', 9, 18]
let novoArr = parseInt(lista[1])

let soma = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < lista.length; x++) {
    soma += lista[x];
}
console.log(soma)
console.log(novoArr)
```

o problema é que eu nao consegui alterar a lista

então eu fiz de um jeito meio tosco :

```
function convertendo(a,b,c,d){
    return a + b + c + d
}

const lista = [1, '4', 9, 18]

a = lista[0]
b = parseInt(lista[1])
c = lista[2]
d = lista[3]


console.log(a + b + c + d)
```

resultado:

```
32
```

alguns testes:

```
const lista = [1,'4',9, 18]

console.log(lista[0] + parseInt(lista[1]) + lista[2] + lista[3])
```

resultado:

```
32
```

como eu posso melhorar esse exercicio ?
Obrigado a todos da comunidade!

Comment: É só usar o `parseInt` dentro do loop. Seria a mesma ideia do código final. Use `parseInt` pra tudo (não deve ter nenhum overhead, mas não posso confirmar) ou faça a checagem do tipo antes (usando `typeof`).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta: ***Mudar String para Number em uma lista*** sobre um `array` onde um item é um texto deve sempre verificar se esse texto corresponde a um número realmente, não é só conversão, mas, é verificar se o mesmo passou na conversão, perguntando primeiramente se é do tipo número e se não for tentar converte para um número, exemplo:

```js
let soma = 0;
const lista = [1, '4', 9, 18, '1', 'a', '7'];
for(let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
  if (typeof lista[i] === 'number') {
    soma = soma + lista[i];
  } else {
    const value = Number(lista[i]);    
    if (isNaN(value) === false) {
      soma = soma + value;
    }
  }  
}

document.getElementById("result").textContent = soma;
```

```html
<div id="result">0</div>
```

O [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) retorna um valor `string` com o nome do tipo de dado que podem ser:

- string
- number
- boolean
- object
- undefined

```js
document.getElementById("n1").textContent = (typeof 42);
document.getElementById("n2").textContent = (typeof 42.0);
document.getElementById("n3").textContent = (typeof 'blubber');
document.getElementById("n4").textContent = (typeof true);
document.getElementById("n5").textContent = (typeof undeclaredVariable);
document.getElementById("n6").textContent = (typeof {});
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 11pt">
  <div>
    <span>42: </span>
    <span id="n1" style="color:blue"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>42.0: </span>
    <span id="n2" style="color:blue"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>'blubber': </span>
    <span id="n3" style="color:blue"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>true: </span>
    <span id="n4" style="color:blue"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>sem declaração de variável: </span>
    <span id="n5" style="color:blue"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>object: </span>
    <span id="n6" style="color:blue"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>Referencia: [MDN - plus: typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)</sup>

Na conversão para número utilize `Number` em vez de `parseInt`, porque o `parseInt` tem problemas como por exemplo: `7a` a função converte para **7** e isso é um erro diferente do `Number` que não converte e retorna [isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) com o retorno ***verdadeiro***, exemplo:

```js
//ERROR, problema na conversão
document.getElementById("n0").textContent = parseInt('7a');
//Ok
document.getElementById("n1").textContent = Number('7a');
//Ok
document.getElementById("n2").textContent = parseInt('7');
//Ok
document.getElementById("n3").textContent = Number('7');
```

```html
<div id="n0"></div>
<div id="n1"></div>
<div id="n2"></div>
<div id="n3"></div>
```

por isso após a conversão sempre teste com a função [isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) se o retorno for diferente de `NaN`, ou seja, `isNan(value) === false`.

Existe também uma forma de conversão que é colocando o operador (**+**) antes do valor texto que tem o mesmo simbolismo que `Number`, exemplo:

```js
//ERROR, problema na conversão
document.getElementById("n0").textContent = +'7a';
//Ok
document.getElementById("n1").textContent = +'7';
```

```html
<div id="n0"></div>
<div id="n1"></div>
```

Comment: o voto negativo, a rede doente e a vida que segue!

Comment: Me ajudou muito eu dividi a questoes em partes e li varias vezes a documentacao, porem nao consegui aplicar ela pela minha falta de conhecimento . Muito obrigado por compartilhar conhecimento novic tenha um otimo final de semana